# android:targetSdkVersion changes after signing the apk and uploading it to Google Play

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, google-play, sign

I have an app with `android:targetSdkVersion="4"`. This is because it is an "old" app and because to get the MENU s/w button in the **below** navigation bar. It cannot be above. During testing everything was fine, but after signing the apk and uploading it to Google Play, I downloaded it, and the MENU button was at the top, on the Action bar - and by the way, the Action bar was not my own Action bar, it was replaced by a default Action bar (different color, size). It seems like the target sdk version changes... How could this happen?

Edit: I am testing it on android version 4.2

Comment: This is the default behavior. If you have menu items in your app and you run it on Android 3.0+, then those items will be shown in the action bar. And target SDK version does not change.

Comment: Than how do you explain that the menu is at the bottom during testing on a device and it is above after downloading the same apk from the play store to the same device? It should only appear above if the target sdk version is set to 11 or above. I wouldn't ask if the behaviur would be the same during testing and after release